# Testing RADSEC with FreeRadius

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp, radius, freeradius

I'm new to RADIUS, servers, and the like. There doesn't seem to be that much documentation on FreeRadius, and I need to get FreeRadius server (3.0.8) running RADSEC for test purposes.

I moved `etc/raddb/sites-available/tls` to `etc/raddb/sites-enabled/` in order to enable "RADSEC".

Questions:

- I understand that I need to have a server certificate as well as a public key. I am wondering on if I could get a fake certificate/key just for testing.
- Also I'm not sure how I can test the actual server, there's the `radtest` command (I've been trying to run `radtest -P tcp -x testing password 127.0.0.1:2083 10 testing123` but it's returns:

> ```
>  ... new connection request on TCP socket
> Listening on auth+acct from client (127.0.0.1, 40542) -> (*, 2083, virtual-server=default)
> Waking up in 0.4 seconds.
> (0) Initiating new EAP-TLS session
> (0) Setting verify mode to require certificate from client
> (0) Non-TLS data sent to TLS socket: closing
> Closing TLS socket from client port 40542
> Client has closed connection
>  ... shutting down socket auth+acct from client (127.0.0.1, 40542) -> (*, 2083, virtual-server=default)
> Waking up in 2.9 seconds.
> ... cleaning up socket auth+acct from client (127.0.0.1, 40542) -> (*, 2083, virtual-server=default)
> Ready to process requests
> ```

Do I need to set up another server as a client so that they can perform the TLS negotiation? And once I do that, how do I get that server to communicate with this RADSEC server?

Answer (score 1):

`radtest` is attempting a non TLS connect to the server. And thats the reason you are seeing that the server disconnects the connection immediately.

You can explore [radsecproxy](https://software.nordu.net/radsecproxy/). It supports TLS (RadSec), as well as RADIUS over TCP. So it can happen as intermediary for the non TLS client and TLS server.